# Why is the semisimple part of a derivation a derivation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If $ A $ is a finite-dimensional algebra over an algebraically closed field and $ T $ is a derivation of $ A $ with decomposition $ T = S + N $ where $ S $ is semisimple and $ N $ is nilpotent, why is $ S $ a derivation of $ A $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a basis of the algebra so that $T$ consists of Jordan blocks $J_1, \cdots, J_k$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_k$. Let $v_{i, 1}, \cdots, v_{i, m_i}$ be the corresponding basis vectors for $J_i$, so that $(J_i- \lambda_i) v_{i, 1} =  0$ and $(J_i- \lambda_i) v_{i, l} = v_{i, l-1}$ for $1 < l \leq m_i$.

It suffices to check that $S(AB) = S(A)B+AS(B)$ when $A, B$ are basis vectors, i.e. for $A = v_{i, l}, B = v_{i', l'}$, $S(AB) = (\lambda_i + \lambda_{i'})AB$, or $AB$ is a generalized eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i + \lambda_{i'}$.

This can be proved by induction on $n = l + l'$. If $n = 2$, then $A, B$ are eigenvectors of $T$, so $T(AB) = T(A)B + AT(B) = (\lambda_i + \lambda_{i'})AB$, so $AB$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i + \lambda_{i'}$. Suppose this is true for all $2 \leq n < l + l'$. Then $(T - \lambda_i - \lambda_{i'}) (AB) = v_{i, l-1} v_{i', l'} + v_{i, l} v_{i', l' - 1}$, and the right side is a generalized eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i + \lambda_{i'}$ by induction, so the same is true for $AB$.